# getting unique records using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql Log table with two columns like this:

```
RegistrantID   compnayID 

1                1
1                1
2                1
3                1
1                2
2                2
2                2
3                2
```

I am using following query to get unique `RegistrantID`s

```
    SELECT 'Number of unique Profile views' AS Data, 
           4 AS Action,
           COUNT(DISTINCT RegistrantID) AS Counts
     FROM dbo.hr_ActionLog 
    WHERE Action = 4 
       AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(ActionDate) >= dbo.DateOnly(@DateFrom))
       AND (@DateTo IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(ActionDate) <= dbo.DateOnly(@DateTo))
       AND (@CompanyID IS NULL OR CompanyID = @CompanyID)
       AND (@RegistrantID IS NULL OR RegistrantID = @RegistrantID)
       AND (@VacancyID IS NULL OR VacancyID = @VacancyID)
```

But now I want to get unique `RegistrantId`s by company so that if a `registrantid` is for two different companies then it will be added twice but if it is more than once for a `companyid`, then it will be added once. With above data count should be 6.  Do I need to use group by ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'Number of unique Profile views'                AS Data, 
       4                                               AS Action, 
       Count(DISTINCT Cast(REGISTRANTID AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' 
                      + Cast(COMPNAYID AS VARCHAR(5))) AS Counts 
FROM   DBO.HR_ACTIONLOG
```

By `COUNT`ing on concatenation of the two columns, we can count the amount of unique rows between both of them.

I removed the WHERE conditions so I could set up a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/817e2/9).
Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without GROUP BY just replace your COUNT to COUNT by complex value for examle:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(RegistrantID as VARCHAR(100))
              +'-'+CAST(CompanyID as VARCHAR(100)) 
) AS Counts
```